# Calling overridden functions in C++ with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I'm having trouble with a multiple inheritance usage case (it's not my project, I didn't decide the inheritance scheme, sorry). Anyway, I can't seem to call a protected `virtual` member function from an overriding function. Here's a simplified class structure:

```
class Base {
    protected:
        virtual void foo() { }
};

class A: virtual public Base {
    protected:
        virtual void foo();
};
void A::foo() { printf("Hello A\n"); }

class B: virtual public Base {
    protected:
        virtual void foo();
};
void B::foo() { printf("Hello B\n"); }

class AB: public A, public B {
    protected:
        void foo();
};
void AB::foo()
{
    A::foo();
    B::foo();
}
```

I would expect that if I call `AB`'s `foo()`, I'll get output that looks like

```
Hello A
Hello B
```

However, when I compile, I get an errors like:

```
error #308: function "A::foo" is inaccessible
    A::foo();
       ^
error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
    A::foo();
    ^

error #308: function "B::foo" is inaccessible
    B::foo();
       ^
error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
    B::foo();
    ^
```

Even if I make all of the `foo`s public, I still see this. What's wrong?

Comment: Works in MSVC. What compiler are you using? It looks like it thinks `AB::foo()` is not a member of `AB`, double check the signature is identical in your non-simplified version..

Comment: Yes, compiles fine in MSVC! Please state the compiler, version, and any compiler flags (if you are using any).

Comment: http://codepad.org/7vxKWShz

Comment: I realized that I had typo'd -- `void foo()` and `void AB::foo()` are very different!

Answer (score 0):

The specific object can be `*this`, so `this->A::foo()` and `this->B::foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was not defining my function in the correct namespace. `void foo()` and `void AB::foo()` are very different!